# Entity framework and transaction in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions

I have question about managing transaction in asp.net application.

For example i have application for planning vacations.

Controller has form to approving vacations.

One user - click save and approve vacation ---- employee which want vacation has - 1 day
second user - clik save and approve vacation and ?

```
//pseudocode

    public void ApproveVacation(int vacationId)
    {
        //pull vacationdata from db
        var vacation = _dbContext.Vacations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == vacationId);
        if (vacation != null && vacation.State != approved) //
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                vacation.state = approved;
                vacation.Employee.Days = -1;
                _dbContext.saveChanges();
                scope.complete();
            }
        }
    }
```

And question is simple, is transaction enough for this scenario or I must use one of concurency technique?

Thanks

EDIT : Context is created one per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction handles atomicity of the operation so if operation modifies multiple database records it will always result in consistent state where all records are correctly modified (if operation succeeds) or all changes are rolled back (if operation fails).

Concurrency handles possible modification of the same record by multiple processes / users because both could load original version of the record but one could save it first so when the second process tries to save a record it can silently override previous changes.

So what are you trying to handle in your code?

Comment: Well, i try handle situation, when two ore more users clicks on forms button and send request to approve vacation (for example). And i need change vactaion state only once with first request

Comment: So you need concurrency mechanism - for example using timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an implicit transaction when calling 'SaveChanges' so there's no need for a transaction scope.

And also, if you would change several items you would need to start the `TransactionScope` before you retrieve the data.